# String Trigger How to Create?

Tags: regex, triggers, zabbix

Hi I need to create a String trigger for the first time.

I need a trigger that check if the word deploy_succeeded from a script

The expression must trigger if anything else from deploy_succeeded appears happens, the strings could be any but after 8 minutes the trigger must alert.

I have create this one, but I am sure that is incorrect.

```
{NETGLOBE NODES FAIL SNMP V3:Netglobe_Nodes_Fail.sh[{HOST.DNS}].regexp("deploy_succeeded")}=1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Have you tried it to see what it does?

Comment: His check is for the string existing, but he wants to detect the cases when string is missing, so it is a simple case of changing 1 to 0 - I explained that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is almost correct. It will alert if the string `deploy_succeeded` appears in the output. To reverse that you would change it to `...].regexp("deploy_succeeded")}=0`.

Note that it will match a substring. If you want to match the exact string alone, use `regexp("^deploy_succeeded$")`. If you want to match substring, function `str()` might be a tiiiiny bit faster.

To check that `deploy_succeeded` has not been there for 8 minutes, use the `count()` function like this: `count(8m,deploy_succeeded)=0`.

Also see [Zabbix trigger function documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).

Comment: Thanks Friend, but how can I set it to check it out if the "deploy_succeeded" change for more than 8 minutes an then display a trigger?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "change for more than" - assuming you want to check for that string missing for 8 minutes, the `count()` should help. Updated the answer accordingly.